# How to bind a property that placed in Viewmodel to each row of Wpf DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

I need something like EllementStyle and EdititngElementStyle for DataGridTemplateColumn,becasue i want to bind a property to each row of datagrid,and this property is inside ViewModel,i have an instance of this property in viewmodel but need to bind difrenent instance of that to each row!(this property is not in DataGrid.ItemSource)

i did something like this for DataGridTextColumn using EllementStyle and EdititngElementStyle,but it seems DataGridTemplateColumn dosen't have this properties?
any idea?

Edit:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn >
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding DataContext.MYProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}"/>    
          </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

i did something like this before for DataGridComboBoxColumn and it works.

```
   <DataGridComboBoxColumn 
          DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="ID" 
          SelectedValueBinding="{Binding DocKindID}">
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
           <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
              <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.DocKindList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
             </Style>
         </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
         <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
             <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.DocKindList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
             </Style>
         </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
     </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Comment: Try CellTemplate and CellEditingTemplate.

Comment: How?i used cellTemplate,but it binds all row to  a single Property,i attached some code.please look at them.